# Microsoft Access Query Count two different criteria in one Query

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

Really Bugging me that i cant do this !!

i am trying to show two columns one call visits and one called Pointless visits from a quantity field.

Visits needs to be a count of all records in Qty field and PointlessVisits needs to be a count of records in the qty field that are equal to zero. i want it t0o show as below

|Visits|PointlessVisits|%Pointless|

1000   |   100         | 10%

Can anyone help?

Comment: You cannot combine different records (some =0 and all the records)

Comment: Is it not possible with a sub query?

Comment: If you can create a relation between it

Comment: How would I go about that ?